# RSpec: check if any model has been saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rspec, mocking

In my Rails application I've created a method that creates a model hierarchy basing on JSON data. I'd like to assure that the method does not save anything to the database. I know I can write test like:

```
expect {
  Importer.import(json)
}.not_to change(Model1, :count)
expect {
  Importer.import(json)
}.not_to change(Model2, :count)
# etc.
```

But I'd like to do it in more generic way. Is there a method in RSpec to check if any model had been saved during a test?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Not sure if Rspec could help you with this, but a quick manual trip to the database might do the job?

```
[Model1, Model2].each do |model|
  model.where('updated_at > ?', Time.now - 2.seconds).count.should eq 0
end
```

Comment: It's quite risky to check update time. If tests run slowly (e.g. because of problems on CI server) one can get strange results. Thanks for the answer, though ;-).

Comment: For future readers: this type of test is particularly error-prone. You should never rely on hardcoded time intervals in testing—this is a broken test, no matter whether it passes sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

If the "import" method can return a Model object, you can write expectation like this:

```
imported_obj = Importer.import(json)
expect(imported_obj).not_to be_persisted
```

The "**be_persisted**" is a [predicate-matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-6/docs/built-in-matchers/predicate-matchers), it simply call **persisted?**  method on imported_obj. The method "persisted?" is  a Rails' method, which return true if  imported_obj  has been saved.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it is not too bad, though it is a bit verbose. 
You could use the `have` matcher.

```
Importer.import(json)
collection1 = Model.all
collection1.should have(5).items

...

collection2.should_not have(5).items

# etc....
```

Though, for your context, reading it like your original test makes more sense (outside of creating a custom matcher that really makes sense). Your testing what the "Importer" is expected to do or not do.

[have(n).items matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/have-n-items-matcher)